# Magento Site design

Tags: database, design

Is the Magento site design linked into its database in anyway?  Meaning if I move a new magento site in on top of the current on, will the existing database make a difference cosmetically?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Cags answer:

There can also be an override of the Design under `System > Design`. You should also check this setting.

Answer (score 2):

The Design Package / theme is set in the database. Therefore if there are multiple packages and/or designs in the code, yes, changing the database could change the appearance of the site. The configuration for this is under `System > Configuration > Design`.